# Can't apply quick action/refactoring to whole solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In visual studio 2022, I'm trying to refactor my code to make it more homogeneous and some of the changes I'd like to apply can be made through the "Quick actions and refactorings" menu, for example removing extra blank lines :

[image: Quick actions and refactorings to remove extra blank lines]

Here, I have an option to remove extra blank lines in the whole solution (or project or document).

My issue comes with other quick action and refactorings occurences like "Convert to interpolated string" :

[image: Quick actions and refactorings to convert to interpolated string]

Why are the "Fix all occurences in ..." buttons not available here? If possible, how could I apply the "Convert to interpolated string" refactor to my whole solution without having to go through every use of string.Format manually?